# jQuery replace specific text from href

Tags: jquery

How do you just change the text "us-test" from the value of the link below, without having to replace the whole link, the current method i use replaces the whole link i guess that has to do with the function of .attr, i'm guessing i could achieve this by using .find or something else i really don't have any clue on how to do it can someone help me on this thank's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("#box1").click(function(){
 $("a.mylink").attr("href", "http://google.com");
   });  

 $("#box2").click(function(){
  $("a.mylinktwo").attr("href", "http://yahoo.com"); 
 });   


<a class="mylink" href="http://google.com/en/get.php?chrome=us-test">Test</a>
```

Comment: You are doing it right by replacing the entire attribute.

Comment: so i guess i can't replace just the specific text i want to, im asking this because im gonna be using a bunch of links and i rather change the text that way it will be less stuff on the file... it will look a lot more cleaner than having  20 long links.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. I wouldn't suggest complicating things too much, and if you can know before hand what URL to go to, replacing the whole URL would probably be best, and easiest to see what's going on.

To replace parts of a string, the replace() method would help.

```
var url = $('.mylink').attr('href')
url = url.replace('us-test', 'replaced-text')
$('.mylink').attr('href', url)
```

You can also pass a regular expression as the matching argument.

Comment: Thanks Rob just what i was looking for, one question tho what does "$('.mylink').attr('href', url)" do :b

Comment: that sets the href attribute for the link that you are trying to update.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
$(".mylink").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr("href").replace(/us-test/, "");
  //or replace with something
  var newHref = $(this).attr("href").replace(/us-test/, "somethingelse");
  $(this).attr("href", newHref);  
});
```

Comment: ummm... i try this and i cant seem to get it working, i guess the problem is on my end, thanks anyways Sudhir...

Answer (score 1):

Use this Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var link = $('a').attr('href');
var equalPosition = link.indexOf('=');

var sptext= link.substring(equalPosition + 1);

 var s=link.replace(sptext,"replaced-text");

  $('.mylink').attr('href', s);




});
```

check this Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/W3pmu/1/
Hope it helps...