# How To Pass URL UTM/SQF Parameters Through SquareSpace Indexed Sub Pages?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-analytics, squarespace, utm

Squarespace Index pages have a main page and a sub page. It looks like the following:

- INDEX (xyz.com/landingpage)

  - Page 1 (xyz.com/landingpage)
  - Page 2 (xyz.com/landingpage-1)

Squarespace cannot pass UTM parameters through a form, so I'm using a script in Google Tag Manager to pass the UTM parameters to Squarespace's SQF format:

Reference: [How to track UTM data in Squarespace form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600462/how-to-track-utm-data-in-squarespace-form-submissions)

Within the forms I have hidden fields SQF_CAMPAIGN, SQF_TERM, etc. that collects the data the script parses and the URL parameters are collected when the form is submitted.

I have a form block on each page of the index. It looks like this:

- INDEX (xyz.com/landingpage)

  - PAGE 1 (xyz.com/landingpage)

    - FORM 1
  - PAGE 2 (xyx.com/landingpage-1)

    - FORM 2

From the the website visitors perspective it is one page and one URL. From Squarespace's design architecture it is considered two pages.

What I'm trying to solve for is getting the URL Parameters to submit with Form 2. Currently Form 1 functions without issue. All parameters are sent. Prior to release I started testing the other form and realized the parameters are not being collected. I tested this on multiple pages.

I suspect that PAGE 2, FORM 2 is not pulling in the data because it is in reality a separate URL. I did test with just using a URL with SQF parameters only and I was able to pull in data on PAGE 2, FORM 2. Although, I need the UTM parameters for further tracking, so using just SQF is not solving my issue. I could be mistaken.

Ideally a user clicks on a Google paid search campaign, therefore all the UTM parameters will be tagged on the landing page URL, and when they submit any form on the pages the parameters will be collected.

Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: The issue is caused by the fact that the snippet of code you are using was written to handle only a single form.

I am the author of the code snippet you included. If you would, kindly remove your reprinted version from your question to avoid confusion for others if/when I update the original answer. Once you have removed the code from your question, I will gladly update the original answer to work for your case as well.

Also (just for the future), do consider attribution of answers you reprint here on SO or elsewhere. https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/#

Comment: @Brandon I'd appreciate that. I'm a new contributor and my understanding was once a question was answered I cannot add additional questions. I created the new post for that reason. I am happy you called this out and informed me of the CC concerns. Happy to comply. Appreciate your work and thanks in advance for updating the original post! I look forward to it. Please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to do regarding my post.

Comment: The only issue was attribution of the snippet. There is no general guideline for my suggestion to remove the snippet, but I simply thought it would help others in the future to not have 3 nearly identical snippets in multiple places (orig. answer, your question, new answer). Technically, your question could have been a follow-up question via comment on the original answer, like "Can this be made to work on a page with multiple forms?" but that of course requires understanding how to word it and knowledge of what's causing the problem. So, no worries. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that the snippet of code you are using was written to handle only a single form. That is, it assumes there's only one form on a given page. It does not have to do with index page architecture in Squarepace.

The issue can be fixed by adding a loop within the code, like this:

```
var i = formFields.length;
while (i--) {
  if (formFields[i]) {
    formFields[i].value = params[param]; 
  }
}
```

The [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57610814/5338581) has been updated with this snippet of code.