# Convert GCLID Parameter To Squarespace Hidden Field

Tags: google-tag-manager, squarespace, google-ads-api

I'm trying to pull a GCLID Parameter (EXAMPLE: https://www.example.com?gclid=CjwKCAjwiMj2BRBFEiwAYfTbCjQ-LBlWhBymAH4piPD3FalPCbl24kE7VQ4JtNJ4Jfj8XPE) from a URL and insert it into a Squarespace hidden field.

Ideally, I'd like to do this through a GTM script, but I can also add it directly into Squarespace via site-wide footer code injection. All Squarespace hidden fields start with the prefix "SQF" (in my case, the hidden field is: SQF_GCLID

I've been playing with something like this:

```
`<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  /**
   * Get the URL parameters
   * source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
   * @param  {String} url The URL
   * @return {Object}     The URL parameters
   */
  var getParams = function (url) {
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split('=');
      params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
  };

  /**
   * Get UTM parameters from the current URL, insert them into correspondingly-named Squarespace form hidden fields.
   */
  var params = getParams(window.location.href);
  var param;
  var paramMatch;
  var paramBase;
  var formFields;
  var i;
  for (param in params) {
    paramMatch = param.match(/^gclid(.*)/i);
    if (!paramMatch) {
        continue;
    }
    paramBase = paramMatch[1];
    formFields = document.getElementsByName("SQF_GCLID");
    i = formFields.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (formFields[i]) {
        formFields[i].value = params[param]; 
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>`
```

which is based on the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600462/how-to-track-utm-data-in-squarespace-form-submissions).

There are no other parameters to pass (just gclid).

Comment: If you do it in GTM you can use a query type variable to extract the glcid instead of writing a custom function (after all, GTM is already loaded, so why have extra lines). Also, do you really have multiple hidden fields per page? Else you can reference your field via a DOM type variable with a CSS selector. To actually write the value to the field you will still need a custom HTML tag with some Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why I wrote that code (which you referenced) the way I did, but this simpler version should do what you need, and is more flexible for parameters other than utm, as in your case:

```
<script>
window.Squarespace.onInitialize(Y, function() {
  /**
   * Get the URL parameters
   * source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/
   * @param  {String} url The URL
   * @return {Object}     The URL parameters
   */
  var getParams = function (url) {
    var params = {};
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    var query = parser.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
      var pair = vars[i].split('=');
      params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return params;
  };

  /**
   * Get UTM parameters from the current URL, insert them into correspondingly-named Squarespace form hidden fields.
   */
  var params = getParams(window.location.href);
  var param;
  var paramField;
  for (param in params) {
    paramField = document.getElementsByName("SQF_" + param.toUpperCase())[0];
    if (paramField) {
      paramField.value = params[param];
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So, after trying the above, it looks like this still isn't being captured. I've also tried using GTM (set URL query variable as "GCLID", which works perfectly well), but then I can't seem to get GTM to properly pass the variable into the hidden form field. I've tried to use <script>
  document.getElementsbyName("SQF_GCLID").value = {{GCLID}}
</script>

Comment: However, if I do change the URL parameters to "SQF_GCLID" manually, this works just fine....but doing that in GA will prevent another integration from working, so this is just substituting one problem for another.

Comment: And....just like that with a hard reset and another cache clearing, it worked perfectly. Thanks, Brandon.

Comment: Nice - glad you got it sorted and glad it worked out @SamR . Also, don't forget to accept/up-vote applicable answers here on StackOverflow.