# Tracking UTM parameters in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm trying to implement the Option 1 code suggested by Brandon in ([How to track UTM data in Squarespace form submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57600462/how-to-track-utm-data-in-squarespace-form-submissions))
and it doesn't work for me. I'm using Squarespace 7.0 with Bedford template. Is there a way to troubleshoot the issue? Thanks in advance.

I tried the suggestion given by Bradon and it doesn't store the UTM values in SQF_ hidden fields.